# TRY...CATCH doesn't seem to work

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling, sql-server-2012, try-catch

I have the following piece of code that's just to make sure that the temporary table doesn't exist. If the table exist I want to truncate it.

```
CREATE TABLE #LookupLinks(
        [SyncID] uniqueidentifier,
        [Name] nvarchar(50),
        [SQLTable] nvarchar(50)
    ) --I create this just to test my try-catch

BEGIN TRY
    CREATE TABLE #LookupLinks(
        [SyncID] uniqueidentifier,
        [Name] nvarchar(50),
        [SQLTable] nvarchar(50)
    )
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT N'#LookupLinks already existed and was truncated.';
    TRUNCATE TABLE #LookupLinks
END CATCH
```

What I want this to do:

1. The temp-table is created
2. Attempt to create it again
3. error sends us into the catch
4. table is truncated and everything continues as normal

What happens:

ERROR: There is already an object named '#LookupLinks' in the database.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296(v=sql.105).aspx this will give you a start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because SQL Server parses and validates the whole batch. So when parsing the second `CREATE TABLE` statement, it errors out saying:

> There is already an object named '#LookupLinks' in the database.

See this example:

```
IF 1 = 1 BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #temp(col INT)
END
ELSE BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #temp(col INT)
END
```

It produces an error saying:

> There is already an object named '#temp' in the database.

The workaround is to use `Dynamic SQL`.

```
-- CREATE the table for testing
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#LookupLinks') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #LookupLinks 
CREATE TABLE #LookupLinks(
        [SyncID] uniqueidentifier,
        [Name] nvarchar(50),
        [SQLTable] nvarchar(50)
    ) 


-- Final query
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#LookupLinks') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE #LookupLinks
    PRINT N'#LookupLinks already existed and was truncated.'
END
ELSE BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    SELECT @sql = '
        CREATE TABLE #LookupLinks(
            [SyncID] uniqueidentifier,
            [Name] nvarchar(50),
            [SQLTable] nvarchar(50)
        )'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    PRINT N'#LookupLinks was created.'
END
```

---

If you do not have the first `CREATE TABLE` statement,your query will work just fine. Or if you put a `GO` before the `BEGIN TRY`.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#LookupLinks') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #LookupLinks -- DROP FIRST

CREATE TABLE #LookupLinks(
        [SyncID] uniqueidentifier,
        [Name] nvarchar(50),
        [SQLTable] nvarchar(50)
    ) --I create this just to test my try-catch
GO
BEGIN TRY
    CREATE TABLE #LookupLinks(
        [SyncID] uniqueidentifier,
        [Name] nvarchar(50),
        [SQLTable] nvarchar(50)
    )
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT N'#LookupLinks already existed and was truncated.';
    TRUNCATE TABLE #LookupLinks
END CATCH
```

Still, it's because SQL server parses and validates the whole batch. The `GO` statement will put the statements into their own batches, thus the error is now not happening.

Even CeOnSql's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31020763/2203084) will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you really want to achieve is this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#LookupLinks') IS NOT NULL --Table already exists
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE #LookupLinks
    PRINT N'#LookupLinks already existed and was truncated.'; 
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
    CREATE TABLE #LookupLinks(
        [SyncID] uniqueidentifier,
        [Name] nvarchar(50),
        [SQLTable] nvarchar(50)
    )
END
```

[image]

Comment: Please try to reconnect to your server to get a clean session, it works perfect for me.

Comment: works fine for me as well. I would reverse the order of the PRINT and TRUNCATE. Since the lookup was not actually truncated at the time it prints the message

Comment: @CeOnSql still the same thing.. Are you using sql-server-2012?

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson tested in sqlserver 2012, 2008 and 2005. Works fine

Comment: @wewesthemenace Got it to work when I followed ur updated explanation! Thanks to both you and CeOnSql =)

Comment: You're welcome! @t-clausen.dk thank you didn't have a look a that - i changed truncate and print to the correct order :)

Answer (score 2):

`TRY CATCH` is for run time error. What you are getting is a compile time error. Add a `PRINT 1` before your statement and you'll see that nothing is getting executed.

```
print 1

    CREATE TABLE #LookupLinks(
        [SyncID] uniqueidentifier,
        [Name] nvarchar(50),
        [SQLTable] nvarchar(50)
    );
BEGIN TRY

    CREATE TABLE #LookupLinks(
        [SyncID] uniqueidentifier,
        [Name] nvarchar(50),
        [SQLTable] nvarchar(50)
    );
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT N'#LookupLinks already existed and was truncated.';
    TRUNCATE TABLE #LookupLinks
END CATCH
```

Comment: Just tried running this, it still errors out: > There is already an object named '#LookupLinks' in the database.

Comment: Oh! Thanks. Didn't realize that I was going about this all wrong ^^

Comment: @wewesthemenace - yes it will as I just gave an explanation as to why it happens. I didnt offer any solution as OP was just trying to see why it was happening